# Cause Property to Fire Toggle Checkbox WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

How can I get a property change to register for a checkbox toggling? I'd like my Save button to enable when a checkbox is toggled but cannot get the property change to fire so I can call RaiseCanExecuteChanged. My checkbox is in a DataGrid. IsGeneric is a property of ProgramsSelected I added the property to my view model to see if that would help but it did not.

XAML

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ProgramSelected}"
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsGenericView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Is Generic" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button Command="{Binding SaveProgramsCommand}" Content="Save Programs" />
```

Program Class

```
namespace OPP.Models
{
    using SimpleMvvmToolkit;

    public class Program : ModelBase<Program>
    {
        private bool isGenericView;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }

        public bool IsGenericView
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isGenericView;
            }

            set
            {
                this.isGenericView = value;

                this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsGenericView);
            }
        }

        public bool ShowAtTop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ManageProgramsViewModel : ViewModelDetailBase<ManageProgramsViewModel, Program>
{
    public ICommand SaveProgramsCommand
    {
    get
    {
        return this.saveProgramsDelegate
            ?? (this.saveProgramsDelegate = Helpers.DelegateCommandFactory.CreateCommand(this.SavePrograms, this.CheckCanSavePrograms));
    }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<Program> Programs
{
    get
    {
        return this.Programs;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.programs = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.Programs);
    }
}

public Program ProgramSelected
{
    get
    {
        return this.programSelected;
    }

    private set
    {
        this.programSelected = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ProgramSelected);
    }
}

public bool IsGenericView       // Never hits the breakpoint when I check or uncheck my checkbox
{
    get
    {
        return this.isGenericView;
    }

    set
    {
        this.isGenericView = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.IsGenericView);

        this.CanSavePrograms = !this.CanSavePrograms;
    }
}

public bool CanSavePrograms
{
    get
    {
        return this.canSavePrograms;
    }

    set
    {
        this.canSavePrograms = value;

        Helpers.DelegateCommandFactory.RaiseCanExecuteChanged(this.SaveProgramsCommand);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show me `Program` class ?

Comment: Program class? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Sorry...I know what you mean...adding now.

Comment: `Program` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I've made the suggested change but still do not see the property firing. Is there anything else I'm missing? Is the model correct as is?

Comment: Does it initialize the CheckBox checked state to the correct value of `IsGenericView`? You have two `IsGenericView` properties. Pretty sure you should put the breakpoint in the one belonging to `Program`. Also, for me looks like it's ignoring `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. I have to select a different row before the binding updates the source property.

Comment: The DataGrid is bound to the collection of `Program` objects, and the column is bound to the `Program`'s `IsGenericView` property. The `IsGenericView` property in your __ViewModel__ is totally irrelevant now, you need to connect it to `ProgramSelected.IsGenericView`.

Comment: Apparently I am not smart enough to get a checkbox inside a Datagrid to notify the property to change. Thank you all for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you should use `DataTrigger`:

```
...
<Button Command="{Binding SaveProgramsCommand}" Content="Save Programs" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ProgramSelected.IsGenericView}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>   
...
```

Class `Program` should implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class Program : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isGenericView;
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsGenericView
    {
        get { return _isGenericView; }
        set
        {
            _isGenericView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsGenericView");
        }
    }

    public bool ShowAtTop { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Also your ViewModel should implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
...
public Program ProgramSelected
{
    get
    {
        return this.programSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        this.programSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ProgramSelected");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I'm still working this and was looking at using your solution but I need the button to be enabled when IsGenericView changes, not just when true.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **ProgramSelected** property should not be private to the *ViewModel*, it should be public for the *View* to write its value.

What I do in this cases is to handle the PropertyChange event of the currently selected element. Note that first you should carefully unsubscribe the event handler from previous selected item.

```
public Program ProgramSelected
{
    get
    {
        return this.programSelected;
    }

    set
    {
        if (programSelected != value){

            if (programSelected != null)
                programSelected.PropertyChanged -= program_PropertyChanged;

                programSelected = value;

                if (programSelected != null)
                    programSelected.PropertyChanged += program_PropertyChanged;      

                NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.ProgramSelected);
           } 
    }
}

private void program_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IsGenericView"))
        RaiseCanExecuteCommands();   
}
```